# Why is an equation that originally had a division through 0, still not defined in that point - after it was removed

Tags: arithmetic

Relearning the basics. When I have the equation: $$2x^2+2x+2=2x^2+2x+2$$ 
$$0=0.$$  I can say that x is any number.

But when i simplify this equation from the following one:
$$2x(x+1+ \frac{1}{x})=2(x^2+x)+2$$ $$\iff 2x^2+2x+2=2x^2+2x+2.$$ $$\iff0=0.$$ I suddenly can't say that x can equal 0, as it isn't defined in my first equation. Why does it matter what my original equation was? Am i destroying information by changing the terms?

Answer (score 2):

It is actually
$$
2x\left( x + 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) = 2 (x^2+x)+2 \wedge x \ne 0 \iff \\
2x^2+2x+2=2x^2+2x+2 \wedge x \ne 0 \iff \\
0=0 \wedge x \ne 0 \iff \\
x \ne 0
$$

Comment: thank you, that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You're not destroying information, instead you're just leaving out an assumption you've made: The first equivalence only holds if x does not equal 0 - otherwise the first expression is undefined.

So rather than destroying information, you're *assuming* that x does not equal zero and then conclude from that, through arithmetic equivalences, that x can take on any value - except, of course, 0.

mvw gave a nice rigorous mathematical notation of what I described.

Comment: thanks a lot, you two made it click very fast